# How to embed/render SSRS report in a ReactJS + .Net core Web API application

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, reporting-services

I have an application developed in .Net core 5 for backend and React JS for front end. I also have some existing SSRS reports which needs to be rendered in the application. How can I embed/render these SSRS reports in ReactJS application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have addressed this problem by generating [URL Access urls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#url-access-syntax) and linking to them. You can also put them in iframes.

```
const makeReportLink = (reportPath, reportParams = {}, zoom = 100) => {
    const reportViewerUrl = 'http://report-server-host/ReportServer_SSRS/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx';
    const reportParamDefaults = {
        'rs:Command': 'Render',
        'rc:Parameters' : 'false',
        'rc:Zoom': zoom,
    };

    let reportSP = new URLSearchParams({...reportParamDefaults, ...reportParams});

    return `${reportViewerUrl}?${reportPath}&${reportSP.toString()}`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neal. This idea worked. I was trying to embed SSRS report in Iframe in a reactjs application and for this we need to add rs:Embed:true parameter.

Comment: But by doing this way, how do we handle authentication to reporting server?

Comment: The parent app has no control over authentication. SSRS may prompt them for a username/password.

Answer (score 0):

I have done following to achieve this

1. Created One POST API, it saves dictionary of Report params in txt file with Unique GUID.
2. Sent Iframe request like http://servername/reportviewer.aspx?reportid= from React app to .Net Application Report Viewer aspx page (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms) with unique GUID, that page gets all params from txt file , sets Authentication , Get Repprt Data from SSRS and show Report Data.
3. Since SSRS opens in IFrame, on refresh it will look for session, which will not be found in React App, for that below web.config additon is required in .net application:

   ```
    <sessionState cookieless="true" mode="InProc" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="8000"/>
   ```

cookieless="**true**" is important other wise you will get "asp.net session has expired or could not be found" Error.